# Need help diagnosing Python/MySQL insert/update anomaly

Tags: python, mysql

I'm learning to access a MySQL database using the MySQL Connector/Python library downloaded from the mysql.org web site. My environment is OS X 10.6, Eclipse Indigo with PyDev, and newly installed versions of MySql (5.5.28, 64-bit), Sequel Pro, and phpMyAdmin.

My test database has one table "Employees", which has columns "id", "name", and "ssn". Initially, there are two rows: (1, Lucy, 1234) and (2, Alex, 3456).

Here is the Python script. The variable "config" contains valid access information for the database.

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

config = {…}

try:
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
        print("Something is wrong your username or password")
    elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
        print("Database does not exist")
    else:
        print(err)
else:
    print ("original database contents")

    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    query = ("SELECT name, ssn FROM Employees")  # fetches all employees names and ssns
    cursor.execute(query)
    for (name, ssn) in cursor:  # iterates over fetched data
        print(name, ssn)  # print one employee per line
    cursor.close;

    # block 1: insert a new employee into row 3
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Employees (id, name, ssn) VALUES (3, 'Sam', '5678')")
    cnx.commit()
    cursor.close()

    # block 2: update the name in the first row
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    cursor.execute("UPDATE Employees SET name='Ethel' WHERE id=1")
    cnx.commit;
    cursor.close()

    print ("after inserting Sam and updating Lucy to Ethel")

    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    query = ("SELECT name, ssn FROM Employees")  # fetches all employees' names and ssns
    cursor.execute(query)
    for (name, ssn) in cursor:  # iterates over fetched data
        print(name, ssn)  # print one employee per line
    cursor.close;

cnx.close()

print ("end of database test")
```

Running the Python script on the initial database with the insert, then update yields:

```
original database contents
(u'Lucy', u'1234')
(u'Alex', u'3456')
after inserting Sam and updating Lucy to Ethel
(u'Ethel', u'1234')
(u'Alex', u'3456')
(u'Sam', u'5678')
end of database test
```

Viewing the database with phpMyAdmin or Sequel Pro **still shows "Lucy"** as the name in row 1.

Running the Python script on the initial database with update, then insert (reversing the order of block 1 and block 2 in the script) yields:

```
original database contents
(u'Lucy', u'1234')
(u'Alex', u'3456')
after inserting Sam and updating Lucy to Ethel
(u'Ethel', u'1234')
(u'Alex', u'3456')
(u'Sam', u'5678')
end of database test
```

Viewing the database with phpMyAdmin or Sequel Pro **now shows "Ethel"** as the name in row 1.

Starting with the initial database open in Sequel Pro, I can execute the two queries in either order and get the correct results.

It seems that something related to committing changes to the database is going wrong, but as a newbie, I'm not seeing it. I would appreciate help in diagnosing this problem.

Comment: There is no need to use `;` semicolons in python code.

Comment: There is also no need to wrap string assignments with `x = ("foo")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to *call* the commit method to commit your changes to the database, otherwise the transaction is never saved and other connections won't see the changes.

```
cnx.commit()
```

You omitted the `()` parenthesis in your code.

You also reference the `cursor.close` method in several locations without calling it; not as big a deal as Python will automatically clean those up through garbage collection.

Comment: Not that this other part is as critical, but the OP also doesn't close the cursor after the first query: `cursor.close;`